# Next.js and Nest.js authentification

Tags: reactjs, next.js, nestjs, redux-saga

I have a project where I use Next.js on the front-end and Nest.js on the back-end.

I want to use a JWT authentification method via email and password.

My question is:
What is the best way to implement an authentification for Next.js with custom Back-end.

I'm sending API requests through redux-saga to get some data from back-end.
For me the Set-Cookies from the back-end not work. It's not applying on the client browser.

For now my possible solution is to create a custom axios instance and somehow do the Auth check there.

But I'm sure there should be a better solution, thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For now my possible solution is to create a custom axios instance and somehow do the Auth check there.

Yes. This is the correct way of going about it. Give the token to whatever you use for queries and let it handle it for you.

You have a number of different ways of achieving this.

1. Provide it via a side-effect

Whenever a login event happens, run a side-effect to configure your axios instance to always send the newly acquired token with each request

2. Set the token in your cookies or localstorage and let axios retrieve it for each request
3. Set the token in a context and only make requests through that context with a hook

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to go with that)